# React - Clear form after submit with Context API state management

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui, react-state-management, react-context

I have a simple Expense Tracker with a form to add transactions to a mongoDB back-end. I'm using the context API and material UI form sub components. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to clear the text fields after onSubmit is fired, but I'm very new to React and Javascript in general. I've seen some other posts about creating a function to fire as onClick with the button, but I'm not sure this is the right route since I have an "initialState" in my Global Context. I've also seen other routes that used the appReducer to do this, but I couldn't figure out how to apply that. To be clear, I'm wanting this to clear the form onSubmit, not a button to click "clear fields". Below is my code:

**Form Component**

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { GlobalContext } from "../context/GlobalState";

// UI for Text Field
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";

// UI and utils for date picker
import "date-fns";
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
import {
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
  KeyboardDatePicker
} from "@material-ui/pickers";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    "& > *": {
      align: "center",
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      width: 200,
      flexgrow: 1
    }
  },
  textfield: {
    height: 38
  },
  button: {
    height: 38,
    align: "center"
  },
  grid: {
    fullwidth: true,
    direction: "row",
    justify: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
}));

export const AddTransaction = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [transactionDate, setTransactionDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState(0);

  const { addTransaction } = useContext(GlobalContext);


  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newTransaction = {
      transactionDate,
      text,
      amount: +amount
    };

    addTransaction(newTransaction);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h3 align="center">Add new transaction</h3>
      <Grid container className={classes.grid}>
        <form
          className={classes.root}
          noValidate
          autoComplete="off"
          onSubmit={onSubmit}
        >
          <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
            <KeyboardDatePicker
              disableToolbar
              variant="inline"
              format="MM/dd/yyyy"
              margin="normal"
              id="Transaction Date"
              label="Transaction Date"
              onChange={e => setTransactionDate(e)}
              value={transactionDate}
              KeyboardButtonProps={{
                "aria-label": "change date"
              }}
            />
          </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
          <TextField
            className={classes.textfield}
            id="Transaction Name"
            label="Transaction Name"
            variant="outlined"
            size="small"
            type="text"
            margin="dense"
            onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}
            value={text}
            required = {true}
          />
          <TextField
            className={classes.textfield}
            id="Amount"
            label="Amount"
            variant="outlined"
            size="small"
            type="number"
            margin="dense"
            onChange={e => setAmount(e.target.value)}
            value={amount}
            required = {true}
          />
            <Button
              className={classes.button}
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              type="submit"
              fullwidth
            >
              Add transaction
            </Button>
        </form>
      </Grid>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

**Global State**

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from 'react';
import AppReducer from './AppReducer';
import axios from 'axios';

// Initial state
const initialState = {
  transactions: [],
  error: null,
  loading: true
}

// Create context
export const GlobalContext = createContext(initialState);

// Provider component
export const GlobalProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AppReducer, initialState);

  // Actions
  async function getTransactions() {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get('/api/v1/transactions');

      dispatch({
        type: 'GET_TRANSACTIONS',
        payload: res.data.data
      });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: 'TRANSACTION_ERROR',
        payload: err.response.data.error
      });
    }
  }

  async function deleteTransaction(id) {
    try {
      await axios.delete(`/api/v1/transactions/${id}`);

      dispatch({
        type: 'DELETE_TRANSACTION',
        payload: id
      });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: 'TRANSACTION_ERROR',
        payload: err.response.data.error
      });
    }
  }

  async function addTransaction(transaction) {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }

    try {
      const res = await axios.post('/api/v1/transactions', transaction, config);
      dispatch({
        type: 'ADD_TRANSACTION',
        payload: res.data.data
      });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: 'TRANSACTION_ERROR',
        payload: err.response.data.error
      });
    }
  }

  return (<GlobalContext.Provider value={{
    transactions: state.transactions,
    error: state.error,
    loading: state.loading,
    getTransactions,
    deleteTransaction,
    addTransaction
  }}>
    {children}
  </GlobalContext.Provider>);
}
```

App Reducer

```
export default (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'GET_TRANSACTIONS':
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        transactions: action.payload
      }
    case 'DELETE_TRANSACTION':
      return {
        ...state,
        transactions: state.transactions.filter(transaction => transaction._id !== action.payload)
      }
    case 'ADD_TRANSACTION':
      return {
        ...state,
        transactions: [...state.transactions, action.payload],
      }
    case 'TRANSACTION_ERROR':
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.payload
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to solve this with help from my brother. He suggested it wasn't ideal to manage the form's private state separate from my Global State, but this got the job done. I reset the form state following the addTransaction call.

**Form Component**

```
//No changes to import or styling //

export const AddTransaction = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [transactionDate, setTransactionDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState(0);

  const { addTransaction } = useContext(GlobalContext);


  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newTransaction = {
      transactionDate,
      text,
      amount: +amount
    };

    addTransaction(newTransaction);

    // Here is what I've added that will return the form to it's original state

    setText('') //this resets the textfield to an empty string
    setAmount(0) //same as above but 0 amount

  };

//no changes to return//
```

Answer (score 0):

hello and thank you for asking your question.

the way I would solve this problem is by using the usestate hook for an input field then setting it to zero with onCLick. 
Here is an example:

suppose I have an input field called search on my website which is connected to the google search. Meaning that a search bar on my website calls the search bar on google.Once the user inputs a value and clicks search I will call setSearch() to a the new value which is the input of the user.

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState(""); // for user input

//once the user inputs a value and clicks a button I will call **two functions** 

//The first fires off a google search
const searchRequest = () => {
    window.open(`https://www.google.com/search?q=${search}`, `_blank`);
  };

// the second function does what you want, it sets the value of search to an empty string.

<Button variant="outlined" size="large" 
onClick={(e) => {
searchRequest(e);
setSearch(" ")}} // <-- I think this solves your problem, if you follow my logic.
>
  Search
 </Button>
```

Hope this helps, let me know if I need to make it clearer.

Comment: Hi @nadim95, thank you for your response. Although this makes sense in practice, since I have 2 text boxes and a date picker I have 3 states to update on the form (setTransactionDate, setAmount, and setText). I tried a function to update all 3 following the addTransaction function, but I'm receiving a "bad request error" from my back-end. It seems as if I need to fire addTransaction, then a clearForm function following to re-render the default form state without making any changes to the back-end

Comment: A clear function that sets all three state values to an empty string on the front-end. Once the data is submitted to the backend you need to clear the fields correct?

Comment: Yes but only one is a string, the others are a date and an amount. I'm managing my state with the reducer in React Context, so that's where the challenge is. I've been trying to return to initialState but haven't had much luck figuring that out.

Comment: I will look more into it, but you could declare all three states in your local storage, and fire a clear function that sets all three values to an empty string when the user is submitting the data to the back end. Meaning that the  AddTransaction component will need to import the state from useContext. and the component that is firing the API request with need to import the clear function. I will look more into it though hope this helps.